# Pixel Add/Remove Software not working

Tags: pi-3, pixel

Pixel Add/Remove Software not working.
Pixel version on Pi 3 contains and Add/Remove Software Gnome app which does not seem to work when I attempt to install eclipse CDT? Is there any thing special that must be done before using the Add/Remove Software app?
Any one else having success?

Answer (score -1):

You need to be connected to the internet so the Pixel can download the packages you have requested from the Add/Remove Software library.

Enjoy Pixel :)